# Setting up a staging environment in Elixir with Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to set up a staging environment and running into problems when I compile using anything other than `prod` for my mix env. I’ve tried setting up a custom env called `stag` with a `stag.exs` file and all that but it appears to break. I’m pretty sure its because of this line I see in `mix.exs`:

```
build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
```

The problem is that i see this line in all my deps folders as well. Does this mean that I should be using a `Mix.env` of `prod` even for my staging environments?

Comment: just run: MIX_ENV=stag mix deps.get or whatever mix command you wanted

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've been doing that very thing and it bombs when you attempt to do it as a release binary. I've found the answer to my question (see my answer below). Thanks again!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think I phrased the question correctly. I am creating a release binary and having trouble deploying it in a staging context when I set the `MIX_ENV` to anything other than `prod`. I was trying to create a custom environment called `stag` for staging with its own `stag.exs` config file but that was not working as expected. I think I have found the answer I was looking for:

I've discovered via some Elixir IRC channels that `:prod` is in fact a build mode and should be used for any cases where one intends to deploy. So in other words, my staging deployment should be set to `MIX_ENV=prod` and then either use environment variables for dynamic configuration settings in the `prod.exs` file or, as I have done in this case, dynamically load a deployment specific configuration in `prod.exs` like so:

```
deployment_config=System.get_env("DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG")
import_config "./deployment_config/#{deployment_config}.exs"
```

This approach solved my problem and I am now happily able to run different deployments with their own custom configurations in a release context.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this was super helpful for me and just the answer I was looking for.  AFAICT edeliver / distillery also seem to work as you've described and will build a release under the :prod environment no matter how much you try otherwise. Makes sense now why it's that way though, thanks.